# lxml - saving xml from looping/iterate through excel rows cause error when value for filename the same

Tags: python, lxml

i have following problem: when I loop through excel rows and save each row in a xml file it works, unless the file naming (name comes from column M) has the same value. Then the xml file gets of course overwritten

working since 2 days on everything

On picture the responsable column for file naming is column M.

[image]

I know I need  somehow to include an if statement for this case.

My idea would be for this case to create one xml for that and put 2 "accountsPayableLedger" with the values inside and sum the amounts in the "consildate" under attribute "consolidatedAmount".

Thanks for all help in advance, highly appreciated.

```
def makeroot():
    return etree.Element("LedgerImport")


####open excel file speadsheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('import_spendesk_datev.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Import']

# build the xml tree
for i in range(2,6):
        xmlRoot = makeroot()
        #consolidate = etree.SubElement(xmlRoot, 'consolidate', attrib={'consolidatedAmount': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=16).value),'consolidatedDate': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value), 'consolidatedInvoiceId': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value), 'consolidatedCurrencyCode': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=12).value) })
        accountsPayableLedger = etree.SubElement(consolidate, 'accountsPayableLedger')
        account = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'bookingText')
        account.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=21).value
        doc = etree.ElementTree(xmlRoot)
        doc.write(str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value)+".xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
```

this should be the desired outcome in case  2 rows have same value

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<LedgerImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040" generating_system="DATEV manuell" generator_info="DATEV Musterdaten" version="4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040 Belegverwaltung_online_ledger_import_v040.xsd">
  <consolidate consolidatedAmount="2000">
    <accountsPayableLedger>
      <bookingText>amazon</bookingText>
      <invoiceId>1</invoiceId>
      <amount>500</amount>
    </accountsPayableLedger>
    <accountsPayableLedger>
      <bookingText>amazon 2</bookingText>
      <invoiceId>2</invoiceId>
    </accountsPayableLedger>
     <amount>1500</amount>
  </consolidate>
</LedgerImport>
```

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant code in the question. If the problem is that the names of the XML files may not be unique, please try to provide a [mcve] that illustrates just that. Remove everything else.

Comment: @mzjn thanks for feedback. I tried to minimize the code and to make it more clear.

Comment: It sounds like you first want to group the rows of the sheet by that particular cell, then work from the groups of items.

Answer (score 0):

If you have rows with duplicates and you want to group them together into a single output `Element` or XML file I think one way is to first group the rows from the Excel spreadsheet by that cell value and then make sure you sum up the value:

```
from lxml import etree
import openpyxl
import itertools as it

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'import_spendesk_datev.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Import']

sortedrows = sorted(list(sheet.rows)[2:6], key = lambda r: r[12].value)

for k, rowGroup in it.groupby(sortedrows, key = lambda r: r[12].value):
  root = etree.Element("LedgerImport", attrib = { "name" : str(k) })
  rows = list(rowGroup)
  if len(rows) > 1:
      consolidated = etree.Element("consolidate", attrib = { "amount" : str(sum(row[15].value for row in rows )) })
      for row in rows:
          etree.SubElement(consolidated, "accountsPayableLedger", attrib = { "amount" : str(row[1].value) })
      root.append(consolidated)
  else:
      etree.SubElement(root, "accountsPayableLedger", attrib = { "amount" : str(rows[0][15].value) })
  etree.dump(root) # write out the root to a file wanted instead
```

I am not sure about the exact cell indices, you will need to adapt them.